# Change Category Slug Redirection

Tags: redirect

Hi if I change the category slug of one of my categories, does WordPress automatically handle redirects from the old category slug to the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WordPress only handles changes of individual post slugs, by saving old slugs in post meta.

You could try a plugin, like [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/), to handle old category slug 301 redirects.